# NServiceBus without input queue

Tags: exception, msmq, nservicebus

Is it possible to use NServiceBus in an application without having any input queues?

Reason is, I have an ASP.NET MVC application that sends messages to other applications when something happens (e.g. a new user registers). The web application never recieves any responses or other messages and therefore I would like not to bog the app. with the msmq peeking which throws an exception every second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is supported, just remove the msmstranport config section and all should be fine.  This works against 2.0.1281.0 (net4) version of NServiceBus with no app.config present

```
using NServiceBus;

    namespace SendOnlyEndpoint.Custom
    {
        public class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                var bus = Configure.With()
                    .DefaultBuilder()
                    .XmlSerializer()
                    .MsmqTransport()
                    .UnicastBus()
                    .CreateBus()
                    .Start();

                bus.Send("SendOnlyDestination",new TestMessage());
            }
        }

        public class TestMessage : IMessage
        {
        }
    }
```

More info on send only endpoints [here](http://andreasohlund.net/2010/08/10/send-only-endpoints/)

Comment: If I dont call bus.Start() I cannot send messages.

The bus is not started yet, call Bus.Start() before attempting to use the bus. 
Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The bus is not started yet, call Bus.Start() before attempting to use the bus.

Line 21:         public void FireAndForget(IMessage message)
Line 22:         {
Line 23:             _bus.Send(message);
Line 24:         }

Comment: My wrong, Start needs to be called. Edited my answer to reflect this. Will check 2.1 as well, but given that it's not stable I suggest that you move to 2.0 if you're having troubles

Answer (score 0):

I would try not configuring an input queue.  Bus.Send will use an internal outbound queue to send messages.

Comment: It doesnt appear to be that easy.

I have tried to reduce my configuration to:
Configure.WithWeb().StructureMapBuilder(ObjectFactory.Container).XmlSerializer().UnicastBus().ImpersonateSender(false).CreateBus().Start()

and remove the MsMqTransportConfig section of my web.config but it throws an exception in the Configure()-method.

Comment: I have the following in an ASP.NET app in a HttpModule with no MsmqTransportConfig section in the web.config and am having success with it:
Bus = NServiceBus.Configure.WithWeb()
                .Log4Net()
                .DefaultBuilder()
                .XmlSerializer()
                .MsmqTransport()
                    .IsTransactional(false)
                    .PurgeOnStartup(false)
                .UnicastBus()
                    .ImpersonateSender(false)
                .CreateBus()
                .Start();

I hope it's not an MVC thing, but NSB should not be peeking a queue..

Comment: I get a NullReferenceException during configuration if I do it without the MsmqTransportConfig-section in my webconfig.

Comment: Not sure on that one, where are you starting the bus?  What version of NSB are you using?

Comment: I am configuring NServiceBus in my Application_Start() method.

I'm using NServiceBus 2.1.0.0 (according to the assembly; I downloaded it about a week ago).